# Car: spiraling detail

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

Why do many car antennas have this spiraling detail and how does this relate to the noise level that a lawn mower emits?

I will try to give an explanation, but I would like to know if my reasoning is correct:

[image]

Well, every fluid has a dimensionless dimension called the Reynolds Number (Re). Re is used in fluid mechanics to calculate the flow rate of a given fluid over a surface. In a simplified way, Re measures the degree of turbulence in a fluid; the more viscous a fluid is, the lower the Re and the lower the turbulence observed in the flow.

Cylindrical objects (like a car antenna or the blade of a wire-cutter) moving in a fluid whose Re is close to 100 (and this is the Re of our atmosphere close to the Earth's surface) generate the following flow pattern:

[image]

These vortexes cause a lot of noise, which is why the car antennas have that spiral. The idea is to cause turbulence in the air that passes through the antenna and not allow the formation of these vortexes.

Corded lawn mowers have several wire formats to be used. If you want to generate the least amount of noise possible, you should choose a wire that has a shape similar to that of the spiral antenna. See below the noise level produced by the same lawn mower with normal wire and with the coiled wire.

[image]

Comment: Interesting stuff. I would have thought that this is some kind of magnetic dipole antenna. But this link (https://www.edaboard.com/threads/spiral-antenna-on-cars.341854/) seems to support your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

For the antenna, the spiral structure is not there to minimize noise. It adds electrical *inductance* which, when combined with the antenna's *capacitance* working "against" the metal bodywork of the car roof, resonates the antenna in the frequency band of interest, optimizing its performance while minimizing its physical size.

The radio antenna on my toyota minivan is spiral-wrapped, yet it still sheds vortices at 60MPH and vibrates visibly.

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/automobile-antennas-radial-ribs.238411/#:~:text=That%20spiral%20shape%20actually%20helps,the%20side%20of%20the%20car

Comment: Please correct me as much as you can. This is an answer that most closely resembles mine: https://www.answers.com/Q/What_does_a_spiral_do_on_a_car_radio_antenna

Comment: Basically, these were my sources! However, I am absolutely open to understanding more deeply, if you find any material that specifically proves that the spiral is not intended, or, at least as a consequence

Comment: Noise reduction, it would be great if you would send it to me.